# How to parse text file and connect to database in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to parse the text file but unable to parse the contents under "Columns:", "Records:", "Relationships:" headings.

My text file format:

```
Database
Type: SQL Server 
Connection String:Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;
DBName:FirstDataBase
Tables
    Table
        Name:TableName1
        Columns:
            ID,numeric,4
            Name,name,20
            Designation,varchar,20
        Relationships:
            
        Records:
            9001,XYZ,Director
            8038,MNO,Associate
            9876,LOP,HR
    Table
        
        Name:TableName2
        Columns:
            ID,numeric,4
            Name,name,20
            Designation,varchar,20
        Relationships:
            
            TableName1,TableName2,FK,ID
        Records:
            8038,MNO,Associate
```

My C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter file name");
    string filep = Console.ReadLine();
    string filePath = $"C:\\Files\\{filep}.txt";
    
    List<Columns> col = new List<Columns>();
    List<TableName> tn = new List<TableName>();
    
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
     
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("\t" + "\t" + "Name:"))
        {
            TableName newTN = new TableName();
            string s = line.Split(':')[1];
            newTN.TName = s;
            tn.Add(newTN);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    
        if (line.StartsWith("\t" + "\t" + "Columns:"))
        {
            // Here I'm stuck
        }
    }
}
```

One of my model classes:

```
public class Columns
{
    public string CName { get; set; }
    public string CType { get; set; }
    public string CSize { get; set; }
    public string Ckey { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried various codes but still, I'm unable to parse it. Solutions are welcome and thanks in advance.

I'm stuck at how to make the program read the next lines of particular heading and store it in a list. If it is solved then I can easily make queries and connect to the database.

Comment: Why not use some standard file format like YAML?

Comment: If you have control over the file format, you can make your life a lot easier using a json or xml format. That would allow you to deserialize the meta-data directly into your objects. Note the `sql-server` tag is not relevant to your file parsing question here.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database database = new Database(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public enum STATE
    {
        GET_DATABASE,
        GET_TABLES
    }
    public enum TABLE_FIELD
    {
        NONE,
        NAME,
        COLUMNS,
        RELATIONSHIPS,
        RECORDS

    }
    public class Database
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string connection { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Table> tables { get; set; }
        public Database(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string line = "";
            STATE state = STATE.GET_DATABASE;
            TABLE_FIELD tableField = TABLE_FIELD.NONE;
            Table table = null;
            string[] splitLine;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case STATE.GET_DATABASE:
                            if (line == "Tables")
                            {
                                state = STATE.GET_TABLES;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (line.Contains(":"))
                                {
                                    splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                                    switch (splitLine[0])
                                    {
                                        case "Type":
                                            type = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                            break;
                                        case "Connection String":
                                            connection = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                            break;
                                        case "DBName":
                                            name = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case STATE.GET_TABLES:
                            if(line == "Table")
                            {
                                if (tables == null) tables = new List<Table>();
                                table = new Table();
                                tables.Add(table);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (line.Contains(":"))
                                {
                                    splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                                    switch (splitLine[0])
                                    {
                                        case "Name":
                                            table.name = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                            tableField = TABLE_FIELD.NAME;
                                            break;
                                        case "Columns":
                                            connection = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                            tableField = TABLE_FIELD.COLUMNS;
                                            break;
                                        case "Relationships":
                                            name = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                            tableField = TABLE_FIELD.RELATIONSHIPS;
                                            break;
                                        case "Records":
                                            name = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                            tableField = TABLE_FIELD.RECORDS;
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    switch (tableField)
                                    {
                                        case TABLE_FIELD.COLUMNS:
                                            if (table.columns == null) table.columns = new List<Column>();
                                            Column column = new Column();
                                            table.columns.Add(column);
                                            splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                                            column.name = splitLine[0];
                                            column.type = (COLUMN_TYPE)Enum.Parse(typeof(COLUMN_TYPE), splitLine[1]);
                                            column.length = int.Parse(splitLine[2]);
                                            break;
                                        case TABLE_FIELD.RECORDS:
                                            splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                                            if (table.records == null) table.records = new List<List<object>>();
                                            List<object> row = new List<object>();
                                            table.records.Add(row);
                                            for(int i = 0; i < splitLine.Length; i++)
                                            {
                                                switch(table.columns[i].type)
                                                {
                                                    case COLUMN_TYPE.numeric:
                                                        row.Add(int.Parse(splitLine[i]));
                                                        break;
                                                    case COLUMN_TYPE.name:
                                                        row.Add(splitLine[i]);
                                                        break;
                                                    case COLUMN_TYPE.varchar:
                                                        row.Add(splitLine[i]);
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class Table
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
        public List<Relationship> relationships { get; set; }
        public List<List<object>> records { get; set; }
    }
    public enum COLUMN_TYPE
    {
        numeric,
        name,
        varchar
    }
    public class Column
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public COLUMN_TYPE type { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }

    }
    public class Relationship
    {

    }
}
```